# Why Google APIs Explorer ( Google Partners API) returns 403 PERMISSION_DENIED?

Tags: google-api, http-status-code-403, google-apis-explorer

I search for a similar question but found some outdated and unanswered ones.

So basically I am just trying to play around with Google Partners API and pull some data for now using Google's API Explorer, so:

- I create a brand new project in Google Cloud Platform
- Go To API and Enable Google Partners API the right there and then click on Try it in Google API Explorer.
- But the problem I get the 403 error on any request I tried to make.

In the API Explorer docs https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/ it says I do not need to provide an API key since they use their own.

My understanding is that I should be able to pull the data - but for some reason no matter what I try, I still get this 403.

Note: like I mentioned I am at least trying to make it work within their API explorer.

What am I missing there?

```
 {
 "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The caller does not have permission",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
 }
}
```

Update:

So it appears that you do have to have a permission to call their API. I do have an API key - but it still says I need a permission. I am the primary user of the account so I have no limitations that I could think of on the account.

I will keep digging and see what I find out.

Analyzing their [Google Partner Interface web requests](https://www.google.com/partners/#a_search;lang=en;locn=United%2520States;motv=0), you can see the &key=AIzaSyCi4oosxbZoHR65JXdMVy7eVR......

So logically, this caller, which is identified by this API can make calls. 
So I went to Google API Explorer and plugged their API key and made a request - and surely got the 200 response back. I put my API key back in there to test with the same set up - PERMISSION_DENIED.

Will continue researching though there is not much left to read. Hope my Google bros will help me out here and let me know how to get the permission.

Comment: Are you using OAuth authorization? The Google Partners API indicates you need to provide the OAuth scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/partners". https://developers.google.com/partners/reference/rest/

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @developernaren No, project was put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to turn on "Additional Google Services" in [Google Admin console](https://admin.google.com/) (Apps > Additional Google Services).

Google Admin help: [Manage access to services that aren't controlled individually](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7646040)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31933578)